# save path in database / or \

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I want to save the path of an image in my database. I'm developing on a Windows system.

I'm using

```
setDestination( APPLICATION_PATH . "/userfiles/")
```

In my database I have a path like the following:

```
C:\wamp\www\cheyenne\application/userfiles\test...
```

If I try to use a relative path like `\public\covers` I get an error like "path or directory does not exist".

I'd prefer the 2nd possibility because the former webserver will be an Apache on a Linux.

Comment: So, you're being told the path you are giving it does not exist.  It is telling you accurate information.  Find out what your *current directory* is and change your path accordingly.  Also, where are you entering said path?  Command line?  PHP include?

Comment: Yes thanks! I changed to: ->setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH . "/../public/images/upload")  In my database now of course I have the path like this: C:\wamp\www\cheyenne\application/../public/images/upload\minus.jpg and trouble to show the picture in my form. I would need the path like this: images/upload/minus.jpg. So the questions are: How can I rename the path and how can I fix the backslash in front of the filename. I tried ->addFilter('Rename', "images/upload"  ) but then I have trouble with a temporary filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to store in a database the complete path of your picture. You really should consider to use a relative path and build the complete path on render, with a database view... My point of view is that you can or not know where your application will be and how your application will be deploy.

For example, today, you store your image on the same server, tomorow, because of traffic issues, you move all your pictures on a second server dedicated for pictures... if you store the complete path of your pictures, you have to execute a SQL request to change partial path and update your code. If you have juste a relative path, you just have to change your application configuration. This can be done in a config.local file that override your default configuration.

For the backslash... it's normal, you are on Windows. Use on your code the default php global variable **DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR** instead of "/".

Comment: Yes the hole path was delivered from APPLICATION_PATH. You got the point, I have to little information how to work with a relative path. Can you give me some more information about the config.local file? I have also some problems in losing my layout sometimes, it fits in the same direction.